# How to draw android view on Unity canvas?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

Hi as per question I want draw android view on Unity canvas(maybe rawImage)

in my project I already make Android Plugin with Unity and it works.

this is the android function.

```
public void PlayApplications(String pacName)
{
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Youtuve on");
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    String packageName = pacName;
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

    Rect rect = new Rect(100,800,900,700);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
    ActivityOptions bounds = options.setLaunchBounds(rect);

    startActivity(intent,bounds.toBundle());
}
```

Unity send android package name to android and that function launches applications as multi windows with rect size.

then I want to draw rect on Unity Canvas is there any tips or solutions?

Comment: Unity is its own engine for games so anything that could make drawing slower like working with Android's native UI render engine, I don't believe is possible. Any UI menu screens need to done in Unity.

Comment: Thanks to your opinion, so is there any solutions for draw android screen in unity canvas??

Comment: You should explain with some detail as to what your idea is as generally Android is running Unity not the other way. Your code works because Unity is obeying the Android framework on startup but otherwise is working on its own for drawing pixels If you want to draw in Unity, I would look at Texture2D,